# scraper via puppeeter in node js - got some exectution issues

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, bots, node-modules, puppeteer

this is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const DOG_NAME = 'section.adopt.yd-amuta > div.container > div.row.yd-dog-count > div.col-xs-12 > div.adopt-head > div.row> div.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 > div.adopt-breadcrumb-title > h2 > span';

let names = [];

async function run() {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });

  let pages = await browser.pages();
  let num =1;
for(; num < 6329; num++){   
  await pages[0].goto('http://www.yad4.co.il/dogs#' + num);

  let dogCard = await pages[0].$$('.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-6');

  for (let i = 0; i < dogCard.length; i++) {
    await pages[0].waitForSelector('.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-6');
    dogCard[i].click();
  }
  console.log('Finished clicking.');

  let count = 0;

  while (count < dogCard.length) {
    pages = await browser.pages();
    count = pages.length;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < dogCard.length; i++) {
    let name = await pages[i].evaluate((sel) => {
      return document.querySelector(sel).innerHTML;
    }, DOG_NAME);

    names.push(name);
    await pages[i].close();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${i + 1}` + ':' + `${names[i]}`);
  }
if(num == 6329 ){
  browser.close();
}
}
}
run();
```

I get this error:

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was
>   destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
>       at rewriteError (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:167:15)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   -- ASYNC --
>       at ExecutionContext. (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
>       at ElementHandle.evaluate (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\JSHandle.js:55:42)
>       at ElementHandle. (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
>       at ElementHandle._scrollIntoViewIfNeeded (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\JSHandle.js:181:30)
>       at ElementHandle.click (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\JSHandle.js:282:16)
>       at ElementHandle. (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
>       at run (C:\Users\Shani Balas\Desktop\scraping\appnew.js:20:16)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:19268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:19268) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:19268)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error
>   (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed.
>       at Promise (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:183:56)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at CDPSession.send (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:182:12)
>       at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:107:44)
>       at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:57:17)
>       at ExecutionContext. (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:112:23)
>       at WaitTask.rerun (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\DOMWorld.js:570:65)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:111:15)
>       at Page.waitForSelector (C:\Users\Shani Balas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:1125:29)
>       at run (C:\Users\Shani Balas\Desktop\scraping\appnew.js:19:20)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:19268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)"

what do you think I should do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877263/puppeteer-execution-context-was-destroyed-most-likely-because-of-a-navigation)

Comment: Does `dogCard[i].click();` cause a navigation?