# Puppeteer Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have an app where while logged in I have to reload the page multiple times (because the page hangs on the loading screen in headless mode). Below is my code, it works fine locally with headless:false but on centos 7 server with headless:true it frequently gets the error as the title says.

```
async function isLogin(page: Page) {
  try {
  const element = await page.$("#kc-session-limits-form");
  let dashboardSelector: string = "";
  if (element) {
    await Promise.all([page.click("#btn-submit"), page.waitForNavigation()]);
    console.log("limited session");
  } else {
    console.log("not limited");
  }

  await waitLoaded(page);
  console.log("Ridirecting");

  await page.waitForSelector("body");
  await Promise.all([page.reload(), page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })]);

  if (await checkElementExist(page, ".spinner")) {
    console.log("spinner");
    await Promise.all([page.reload(), page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })]);
  }
  console.log("check error");

  await wait(500);
  const networkError = await checkElementExist(
    page,
    ".list-group-item.list-group-item-action.bb-select-context__item.first.last"
  );
  if (networkError) {
    await Promise.all([page.reload(), page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })]);
  }
  await waitForEl(page, localeSelector);
  locale = await page.$eval(
    localeSelector,
    (e) => (e as HTMLElement).innerText
  );
  dashboardSelector = locale === "VN" ? "aria/Tổng quan" : "aria/Dashboard";
  await waitForEl(page, dashboardSelector);
  return await checkElementExist(page, dashboardSelector);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in isLogin function:", error);
    return false; // You can return a default value in case of an error
  }
}
```

It seems that page.waitForNavigation is not working as expected. How can I ensure the page will wait until it finishes reloading before finding an element on the page?
Thank you very much for everyone's comments.

Comment: Can you share a complete, runnable [mcve] with that page you're manipulating, and the expected output? There may be a fundamentally better way to do it than you may presuppose. Related: [1](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3323), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818869/why-does-headless-need-to-be-false-for-puppeteer-to-work), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877263/puppeteer-execution-context-was-destroyed-most-likely-because-of-a-navigation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to network latency, sometimes waitForNavigation has no chance to handle navigation finished. solution: rmeove promise.all, only use page.reload with waitUntil options,
example:

```js
await page.reload({"waitUntil":"networkidle0"}) //this option default to load
```